# Azure B2C - Display Control - Send email verification with Mailjet

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am following the sample as well as the document that describes custom email verification with Mailjet. I get the password reset journey to work but cannot figure out why I have 2 sets of UI elements as shown in the pic. The one below seems to be the one configured to use Mailjet because the email is formatted as I specified in Mailjet. The one on top sends with the default MSFT email verification format.

Thanks for your help! :)

[image: email verification with 2 sets of UI elements]

Comment: Can you share some code. It would be helpful for us to trace the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have an OutputClaim `verified.Email` in your technical profile that also references your DisplayControl. Remove that output claim and it'll disappear, leaving only the custom email control.

Comment: Thank you @Jas. I don't have an Output claim in the technical profile that references the display control as you said. None in there at all actually. But i do notice notice one in the base file (the one for display controls in the starter pack - <!--DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailControl" /-->). I commented it out and it went away. I am wondering why the "emailControl" display control in the base file didn't get overridden  by my display control in the extensions file. The one in the file is named "emailVerificationControl". Is it because they aren't named the same?

Comment: Yes because the names are different.

Comment: Thank you @Jas. I will mark you answer correct because it was helpful.